# update table with select field1 from table2 where filed3=''

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables as follows

```
 **ipmac2** 
mac                     Monitor
C0:A0:BB:CA:3D:72         on
54:04:A6:95:D0:59         off
00:0B:0E:0F:00:ED         on

**ipmac1**
mac                     Monitor
C0:A0:BB:CA:3D:72         Null
54:04:A6:95:D0:59         Null
00:0B:0E:0F:00:ED         Null
```

so i want to update table2 Monitor field with exact mac is in table1.
i want to get a query to do so. 
the table2 - for Mac '00:0B:0E:0F:00:ED'

```
Mac                        Monitor
00:0B:0E:0F:00:ED           on
```

PLeae help me here .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to update by joining the tables using a common key between them.

```
update table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t1.mac = t2.mac
set t2.monitor = t1.monitor
```

Comment: thats called alias when you join you can specify a alias for table names and use them while accessing the colums, this makes it easy for readability and in some cases when you have long table name you do not need to write it again again. Thats just one usage there are many usage and I am sure you will learn in the due course of time. Best of luck on learning mysql :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
update table2
set monitor = (select t1.monitor from table1 t1 where t1.mac = table2.mac limit 1)
```